# Python json Parsing syntax error?

Tags: python, json

```
import json

Services = {}
Services['Refrigerator repair & services'] = {
 'hello':'a'
'Brand':['Bosch','BPL','Croma','Electrolux','Godrej','Haier','Hitachi','IFB','Kelvinator','Kenstar','LG','Lloyd','Panasonic','Samsung','Sansui','Videocon','Whirlpool']   
}

s=json.dumps(Services)
```

> 'Brand':['Bosch','BPL','Croma','Electrolux','Godrej','Haier','Hitachi','IFB','Kelvinator','Kenstar','LG','Lloyd','Panasonic','Samsung','Sansui','Videocon','Whirlpool']
>
> ```
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

why is this showing and if i remove 'hello' :'a'  than it compiles perfectly ?

Comment: you are missing `,` after 'a'

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Quick spot!

Comment: It's possible that they thought this was such a simple issue / you were so so close...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the `'hello': 'a'`.

Make it:

```py
import json

Services = {}
Services['Refrigerator repair & services'] = {
    'hello': 'a',
    'Brand': [
        'Bosch',
        'BPL',
        'Croma',
        'Electrolux',
        'Godrej',
        'Haier',
        'Hitachi',
        'IFB',
        'Kelvinator',
        'Kenstar',
        'LG',
        'Lloyd',
        'Panasonic',
        'Samsung',
        'Sansui',
        'Videocon',
        'Whirlpool'
    ]   
}

s=json.dumps(Services)
```

Comment: Thanx Problem Solved